# route to reflect hierarchical url/menu structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

i've created a basic mvc3 website whereby each controller represents the first folder in a url structure.

for example, the "food" and "drinks" folders below are controller. there are only two controllers which contain all of the sub-items in them.

ie in the first line of the example, controller=food, method=asian

in the second line controller=food, method=pad-thai and so on and so forth.

www.mysite.com/food/asian/
www.mysite.com/food/asian/pad-thai
www.mysite.com/food/italian/chicken-parmigiana
www.mysite.com/drinks/cocktails/bloody-mary

how would i write routes so that www.mysite.com/food/asian/pad-thai will direct to the food controller and the paid thai method within that controller, and also have a rule to send from www.mysite.com/food/asian/ to the food controller and asian index method??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MVC design pattern isn't for rewriting URLs to point to folder structures. It can do this but it certainly isn't its main purpose.  If you're trying to create a URL structure with static content, it might be easier to use the [**URL rewriting**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060714/how-to-handle-domain-name-in-mvc-routing/9063351#9063351) functionality built into IIS.

If you're creating a full MVC application, set up `FoodController` and `DrinkController` to serve up your views, for example:

```
public class FoodController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult ViewDishByTag(string itemType, string itemTag)
  {

    // If an itemType is displayed without itemTag, return an 'index' list of possible dishes...

    // Alternatively, either return a "static" view of your page, e.g.
    if (itemTag== "pad-thai") 
         return View("PadThai"); // where PadThai is a view in your shared views folder

     // Alternatively, look up the dish information in a database and bind return it to the view
     return ("RecipeView", myRepo.GetDishByTag(itemTag));
  }
}
```

Using the example above, your route might look a little like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "myRoute",
                "{controller}/{itemType}/{itemTag}",
                new
                {
                    controller = UrlParameter.Required,
                    action = "ViewDishByTag",
                    itemtype = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    itemTag = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

Your question doesn't contain much detail about your implementation, so if you'd like me to expand on anything, please update your question.